# I am getting same version name for WSS and MOSS 2007?

Tags: python, sharepoint, version, response-headers

I am getting same version name for WSS and MOSS 2007?

```
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
print response.info().getheader('MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices')
```

I am using the above python code to get the verion of the sharepoint verion using the site URL.

WSS:MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 12.0.0.4518
MOSS:MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 12.0.0.4518
SP2010:MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 14.0.0.4762

So i am confused now because for MOSS and WSS it return the same version id.Why its happening how to resolve it?
Is there any v\way to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version is exactly the same for both. MOSS is nothing more than a couple of extra modules on top of WSS.

Have a look at [this post](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2009/05/how-to-reliably-detect-moss-or-wss-at.html) about how to differentiate between MOSS and WSS from inside SharePoint code.

Not sure if this will help you as you want to look remotely. You may want to consider adding a simple web service to your SharePoint instance. Alternatively try requesting a MOSS only web page and see if that exists.

Comment: Is there any idea to find the version differance. I am using different way. If i call search.asmx to wss site it return "None" so understand that its wss if it returns some other content i consider it as MOSS is that approach correct?

Comment: I don't know, the best thing to do is to give it a try. Note that checking for 'search' the behave in a certain way may be misleading as it is possible to download and install a search server and install it on the plain WSS.