# How to determine if website using SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint

I have a list of websites and I need to determine which ones are using SharePoint (and preferably what version). Is there any way to find it out from headers, HTML code or something else? 
Currently I'm checking for '/_layouts/1033/' string in HTML, but I noticed that some SharePoint sites don't have it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your question may be resolved by the answer to this one : [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309728/how-to-determine-sharepoint-version-using-sharepoint-web-services)

Hope that helped.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Did not come up in the search for some reason. That's exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the response headers.

SP 2007: microsoftsharepointteamservices: 12

SP 2010: microsoftsharepointteamservices: 14

SP 2013: microsoftsharepointteamservices: 15